# Parse != in scala

Tags: parsing, scala

I need to parse statements of the form

```
var1!=var2
var1==var2
```

and so on. I have the following construct:

```
lazy val Line : Parser[Any] = (Expr ~ "!=" ~ Expr)^^ {e => SMT( "(not (= " + e._1._1 + " " +  e._2 + "))")} | (Expr ~ "==" ~ Expr)^^ {e => SMT( "(" + (e._1._2) + " " + e._1._1 + " " +  e._2 + ")")}
```

The second part for the "==" works just fine, returning me `(== var1 var2)`, but the first part just does not parse.  Whatever I try to parse instead of the "!=", neither "!= " nor " !=" or " != " are recognized.

Of course I can replace the "!=" before I hand it to the parser, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: How does it show it just does not like you?

Comment: Uh, that happens if you rewrite a test too often, sorry...
Edited it now!

Comment: What happens if you try to feed `var1 != var2` (this way, with spaces) to the parser?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a more complete example (maybe one which compiles)?

Comment: Hm, the more complete example seems to work just fine!?!

Looks like I have a mixup between two subclasses of the class I try to parse.

`LabelParser.parseAll(LabelParser.Label...`

`lazy val Label : Parser[Any] =  Line | Whatever | ...`

If I parse LabelParser.Line directly, it works just fine...

Sorry for troubling you, I really did not see that at the time..

Thanks for the help, 
regards,
Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this minimal example (Scala 2.9.2):

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

sealed trait ASTNode

case class Eq(v1: String, v2: String) extends ASTNode
case class Not(n: ASTNode) extends ASTNode

object MyParser extends StandardTokenParsers {
  lexical.delimiters += ("==", "!=")

  lazy val line = (
      (ident ~ ("==" ~> ident)) ^^ { case e1 ~ e2 => Eq(e1, e2) }
    | (ident ~ ("!=" ~> ident)) ^^ { case e1 ~ e2 => Not(Eq(e1, e2)) }
  )

  def main(code: String) = {
    val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(code)

    line(tokens) match {
      case Success(tree, _) => println(tree)
      case e: NoSuccess => Console.err.println(e)
    }
  }
}

MyParser.main("x == y")
MyParser.main("x != y")
```

Comment: Btw, since your code hints at writing a parser for an SMT solver's input language, maybe Scala^Z3 (https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3/) is of interest to you.

Comment: Hi,

Thx for the example!!
Found my error when I tried to create a minimal example for here too.

I already use ScalaZ3, thx :)